# Problem with optimization using solnp in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm having some issues with the following problem:

I want to maximize the function U with respect to the constraint B using solnp()

I've defined the U function as:

```
U = function(x){ 
  #P is a vector of parameters
  #X is a vector of variables
  -P[1]*(x[1]^P[2])*(x[2]^P[3])
}
```

And the function B as follows:

```
B = function(x){ 
  #M is a vector of parameters
  #X is a vector of variables
  #The constant M[3] is an argument of CCM
  -M[1]*x[1]-M[2]*x[2]
}
```

Then I've defined the optimizer function this way as a cover of solnp():

```
CCM = function(P,M){
  
  solnp(c(0,0), #starting values (random - obviously need to be positive and sum to 15)
        U, #function to optimise
        eqfun=B, #equality function 
        eqB=-M[3],   #the equality constraint
        LB=c(0,0), #lower bound for parameters i.e. greater than zero
        UB=c(10000,10000)) #upper bound for parameters (I just chose 10000 randomly)
  
}
```

I've written a optimize function to be able to choose different parameters for this problem.

The issue here is that when I run the `CCM` function is does not seem to be maximizing (gives me (0,0) as solution), `solnp()` minimizes by default, so I've changed the sign of `U` and `B` due to that.

By the way, I'm trying to program a Consumer Choice model.

---

### Edit:

Test run with the values in the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830139/problem-with-optimization-using-solnp-in-r?noredirect=1#comment123452807_69830139).

```
P <- c(2,0.1,0.9)
M <- c(1,2,15)
CCM(P, M) 
#
#solnp-->The linearized problem has no feasible
#solnp-->solution.  The problem may not be feasible.
#
#Iter: 1 fn: 0       Pars:  0       0      
#solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.
#$pars
#[1] 0 0
#
#$convergence
#[1] 2
#
#$values
#[1] 0 0
#
#$lagrange
#[1] 0
#
#$hessian
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1
#
#$ineqx0
#NULL
#
#$nfuneval
#[1] 7
#
#$outer.iter
#[1] 1
#
#$elapsed
#Time difference of 0.6487024 secs
#
#$vscale
#[1] 1.0e-08 1.5e+01 1.0e+00 1.0e+00
#

CCM(P, M)$convergence
#
#solnp-->The linearized problem has no feasible
#solnp-->solution.  The problem may not be feasible.
#
#Iter: 1 fn: 0       Pars:  0       0      
#solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Data, please. How do you call `CCM`?

Comment: For example CCM(c(2,0.1,0.9),c(1,2,15))

Comment: The problem is not that `solnp` is not maximizing, the problem is that inverting the Hessian is giving problems, the problem may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
U <- function(val_x, val_P)
{ 
  val_P[1] * (val_x[1] ^ val_P[2]) * (val_x[2] ^ val_P[3])
}

B <- function(val_x, val_M)
{ 
  val_M[1] * val_x[1] - val_M[2] * val_x[2]
}

fn_Opt <- function(val_x, val_P, val_M)
{
  val <- (B(val_x, val_M) - M[3]) ^ 2 + U(val_x, val_P)
  
  if(is.na(val) | is.nan(val) | is.infinite(val))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
    return(val)
  }
}

library(DEoptim)
P <- c(2, 0.1, 0.9)
M <- c(1, 2, 15)

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = fn_Opt, lower = c(0,0), upper = c(10000,10000), 
                       control = list(itermax = 1000), val_P = P, val_M = M)

obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem

 par1          par2 
 1.500000e+01 5.661556e-134 

B(obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem, M)
par1 
  15

U(obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem, P)
par1 
3.135316e-120
```